# how to use Table pagination material-ui react js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, pagination, fetch

Hi I use react js and I'm new. I want to use [Table pagination](https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/#table-pagination) material-ui for a table that does not belong to material-ui.For example, I want 2 row per page.I use the reactStrap table. If possible, tell me how to do it.

```
  render() {
    const items = this.props.items.map(item => {
      return (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>
            <div style={{ width: "110px" }}>
              <Button
                color="success"
                buttonLabel="Edit"
                item={item}
                updateState={this.props.updateState}
              >
                Edit
              </Button>

              <Button color="danger" onClick={() => this.deleteItem(item.id)}>
                Del
              </Button>
            </div>
          </td>
          <th scope="row">{item.id}</th>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
          <td>{item.username}</td>
          <td>{item.email}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div
        style={{
          maxHeight: "600px",
          overflowY: "auto"
        }}
      >
        <Table responsive hover>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Action</th>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>username</th>
              <th>email</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{items}</tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can see my table in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-shape-xlzez?file=/src/DataTable.js).Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1):

I prepared an example **Only for pagination**. You need to work on api calling with the paging parameters. As your api is returning only 10 records, so I set `rowsPerPage: 5` so that you can get the reflection of changing page. but default value should be `rowsPerPage: 10`

```
  state = {
    items: [],
    page: 0,
    rowsPerPage: 5
  };
```

**Update:**

You need update the url with the state value like below:

```
let url = `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${this.state.page +
      1}&per_page=${this.state.rowsPerPage}`;
```

And then call api when you change the page. Please check the **below link** for code.

[Here is the Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/api-call-with-paging-hq4pu)

Comment: tnx.But my question was about API. I think this link is better for you
https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=2

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Pagination from '@material-ui/lab/Pagination';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > * + *": {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  },
}));

export default function PaginationComponent(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setPage(value);
    props.paginationHandler(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Pagination
        count={props.totalCount}
        page={page}
        variant="outlined"
        color="primary"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please add some more context apart from the code on how this would solve the problem mentioned in the question